Как в Delphi 11.x создать apk которое получает уведомления сторонних приложений?
Мне нужно понять как отловить пуши других всех приложений на телефоне, как они приходят, потом обрабатывать их. Так же нужно получить события, например включен ли экран телефона или нет и выводить это в memo.
Я с андроидом знакомлюсь только сейчас, пока ничего непонятно... Разбирал исходники Embracadero, но там не то что нужно, там получение идет, если на пуш тыкнуть, а мне нужно отлавливать пуши.
